# Simulation algorithm question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, simulations

I have been looking at various simulation algorithms, like Barnes-Hut and a few others, and the Laplace operator, the wave equation, etc., and I was wondering why it's necessary to compute the mass/gravity/etc. for every object after the first step. In the case of a gravity simulation, for example, couldn't you use the acceleration of a particle's local objects at step k to estimate the value of the acceleration field and apply that acceleration to the particle at step k + 1? Each particle's acceleration at step k + 1 is calculated from the local particles' accelerations at step k, and you shouldn't need to calculate the effect of the gravity of each particle on each other particle.

I feel like this can't be right, but I also am not sure where my reasoning is wrong. It would be an approximation, but it seems like it would be a pretty good one. Except for the thing I'm not seeing, and I feel like there is one.

EDIT: I think my thought process is not clear on this, and my choice of gravity was not a good example of what I was thinking. I think I'll have to reconsider what I'm asking and ask again some other time.

Comment: It seems Barnes-Hut clumps particles sufficiently far away and close to eachother into a single object when seen from some local anchor point, I don't see you mentioning anything outside the local octtree neighbors so to speak, where do the far away ones come in.

Comment: I think my question is: if I calculate the acceleration of all particles or bodies in step one using a complete survey of all particles, or with Barnes Hut, then the state of the local particles would contain the position of all particles in the system, and therefore to know the gravitational field at the position of each particle, I would be able to determine that by interpolating the topography of the acceleration field based on the other local particles. And each subsequent step would include the updated state of each particle, which would propagate changes across the system. No?

Comment: But when would the long range interactions be updated if you only update using local information?

Answer (score 2):

> In the case of a gravity simulation, for example, couldn't you use the acceleration of a particle's local objects at step k to estimate the value of the acceleration field and apply that acceleration to the particle at step k + 1?

Well this seems to be the crux of the problem: how do you compute $\mathbf{a}_i$ for each particle at each step $k$? The most straight-forward way is slow,<sup>1</sup> but works:
$$\mathbf a_i\simeq F_i\left(\mathbf r_i\right)\propto\sum_j\frac{1}{\left(r_i-r_j\right)^2},\tag{1}$$
but this is the one you want to reject.

It seems like you want to suggest using some sort of average acceleration for local particles, but that would mean that the particles are interacting in some weird way & not gravitationally (which is what you're trying to model). And, on top of that, this method probably would not conserve energy that you should expect in the system.
Of course, if you were computing the force via Eq (1) for local particles and some center of mass force for further away clusters of particles, well then this seems to be the [Barnes Hut algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation) you are describing and is a reasonably popular method (I'm not sure if this is used more than the [fast multipole method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method)).

Similarly, holding it constant would be just as bad because then not only is energy not conserved, but your particles wouldn't even be interacting, gravitationally or otherwise.

<sup>1. This statement is intentionally ignoring algorithms such as Barnes-Hut that can speed up the calculation by clustering particles and using center-of-mass for more distant objects.</sup>

Comment: When I said "after the first step," I was unclearly expressing that I could use your equation 1 or Barnes Hut for the first step. And then using those accelerations for subsequent steps. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, I know. I'm just pointing out that there's no real way for you to "evolve" the acceleration while also maintaining energy conservation. And holding it constant from the first evaluation would be just as bad, since it's definitely going to violate conservation of energy *and* won't even been a gravitationally interacting system.

Comment: From your comment to Emil, it seems you want to only consider local effects of gravity (i.e., only if $r\leq r_\text{max}$). I suppose this could be done, but long range forces can be important and you'd be missing out on those.

Comment: As an example of long range forces being important: consider a single particle orbiting very far from a large cluster. We'd actually expect that the single particle would continue orbiting the cluster, but if you are suggesting a local topography, then that particle will not continue orbiting (mind you, I am not sure how you intend on computing the topography without summing over each particle pair-wise).